# How do we capture logs and share it with IT team for analysis when an Hybrid Mobile App breaks

Tags: logging, sapui5

What we have a is a Hybrid App that is developed using SAP UI5 JS Framework and Cordova. Here I need to capture the logs and then share those logs to IT team for analyzing. But I am unable figure it out what is the best procedure to move forward.

Could you please help me out, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683503/debug-javascript-in-android-emulator-with-phonegap?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Thank you for the response @RafaelLópezMartínez I have gone through the link which you have provided. if I write console.log then how can I share those logs through email for every set of interval. Here my requirement is whenever app crashes then I need to send an email to the IT team along with the log.